# user object not loaded after logging out and quickly logging back in in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I am facing a strange behaviour, and can't debug it properly. I need your help.

If I log out of Meteor, everything seems fine. 
If I wait for around 2 seconds and log back in again, everything is still very fine. But if I logout and quickly login again, right after the login process, the `Meteor.user()` object is set to null, which leads my router to redirect the user back to the login page.

Any idea why this is happening, and how could I prevent it?

I have spent 2h trying several things without success. Any suggestion is most welcome.

**EDIT**

This is my global `onBeforeAction` function :

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  // Ensures the user is logged in
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    please_login();
  }

  // Email address not verified for 24h? Please verify it!
  else {
   var self = this;

   // Waits for the user object to be passed over DDP
   function wait_for_user_data() {
     if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().emails && Meteor.user().profile) {
       var user  = Meteor.user();
       var now   = new Date().getTime();
       var ca    = user.createdAt.getTime();// Created At
       var cs    = (now - ca) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);// Created Since (in days)
       var urls  = ["email_verification_required", "email_verification"];

       if (cs > 1 && 
         !user.emails[0].verified && 
         urls.indexOf(self.url.split("/")[1]) == -1) {
         Router.go("email_verification_required");
       }

       else {
         self.next();
       }
     }

     else {
       setTimeout(wait_for_user_data, 500);
     }
   }
    wait_for_user_data();
  }
}, 
{except: ['home', 'login', 'register', 'password_recovery', "email_verification", "profile"]})
```

**What actually happens is the following :**

When I login right after having logged out, `self.next()` is called, but the current user properties (`Meteor.user().emails` and `Meteor.user().profile`) aren't loaded yet for some reason. They are `undefined`. As you can see, I tried to work around this by waiting until they are defined, but then I receive the following error message :

```
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() 
in an onBeforeAction?
```

This seems to cause Meteor to set `Meteor.user()` to `null`, and so my user gets redirected to the login page...

**EDIT BIS**

This is how I am handling the publish/subscribe of the users data. I have 2 different pub/sub set, one for all users, and the other one for the logged in user only.

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
  var args   = {};
  var fields = {
    '_id':                1, 
    'createdAt':          1,
    'profile.firstname' : 1, 
    'profile.lastname' :  1, 
    'profile.lang' :      1, 
  };

  // Only admins can access those sensible information
  if (this.userId && Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
    fields["emails"]          = 1;
    fields["profile.celular"] = 1;

    args : {$ne : {_id: this.userId}};
  }

  return Meteor.users.find(args, {fields: fields});
});
Meteor.publish('user', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

This is how I subscribe to those two publications within my router's configurations :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate:   'layout',
  loadingTemplate:  'loading', 
  waitOn: function() { 
    return [Meteor.subscribe('user'), Meteor.subscribe('users')]; 
  },
});
```

Comment: could you add some code I think I know how to solve this, but would like to see what you're already doing.

Comment: I have added the information I could. I hope this helps you to help me :)

Comment: Ok from the code above thus is not what I understood toy had done,  there are a couple issues here and tyre best would bee for me to do this is code.

Comment: I also get drunk sometimes, no worries. I got you

Comment: Lol sorry, commenting on my phone while in transit.  Basically will need to write out the code to solve this properly...  Having recently done a fairly large app with iron router though, im now using flow router, which has made dealing with a lot of these issues easier.  But I'll still answer solving this for iron router.

Comment: overall this is not awesome, and bound to be problematic I believe down the road, firstly have you added the conditional to the top of this function correctly?  rather than `!Meteor.userId()`  it should be `(!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn())`  secondly that email verification check should  move out of here, at last for now.

Answer (score 1):

Without a code example (and knowing which router you're using) I'm going to take a guess that you're router code looks something like :

```
 if (!Meteor.user()) {
      //... redirect or change tempalte etc
 }
```

There is another value you can check,

```
 if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      //... redirect or change tempalte etc
 }
```

you can use various combinations of these to handle the login state, such as having a logging in loading view etc

#### With more information

The redirect is being called in a callback, currently for the login with password function, having a look at the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) it should be called on the onLogin callback linked as this ensures that login was successful, though doing the redirect here, may not provide the same range of control as doing this in a reactive context such as a before hook on a controller, or an autorun function created in the login template onCreated callback.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. 

I am actually calling my router from the `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` callback. My understanding is that the callback is called only when the `Meteor.LoggingIn()` value is back to `false`, is that correct?

Comment: I would assume that would be whats causing your issue.  Ideally I would want to decouple it, and rather react to the change in your applications state personally.  but the callback for that function runs whether it succeeds or not,   `http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin` the onlogin callback though, that runs only on success.

Comment: Nop... Thanks again for helping but I am facing the same behaviour. 
Actually it is a little worse, as the `onLogin` callback is called several times for some reason...

Comment: Are you checking that meteor user is true and that your not logging in currently?   Will look through your code example in the morning and see what's going on.  This won't be that hard to solve, it's really about. Working with varying state in reactive contexts and ensuring toy only run in the exactly correct state.

Comment: I am glad you think this is an easy task. I feel kind of stuck. And yes, I am sure that I am not loggingIn which going through the app, I checked. From what I experience, it seems more like a conflict between logging out, and then back in quickly after that. The logging it itself works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've deal with this in the past is to define an explicit subscription to the user object then `waitOn` that subscription in the router. Much simpler than writing a polling loop but mostly I did it because I needed specific fields that didn't come over by default. Hopefully this can help you with your problem.

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  if ( this.userId ){
     // return the fields I need
    return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId },{ fields: { field1: 1, field2: 1, ... }});
  }
  else this.ready();
});
```

Router:

```
waitOn: function(){
  return Meteor.subscribe('me');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. 
Why do you believe this is related to the issue I am facing? I may have missed something here. 

I am actually waitingOn also via a user subscription which is slightly similar to your, although a little different. I am not sure where I could share it to you though, so that we can compare. 

I'll edit my question to do so

Comment: There's a second problem which is that you can't do a `router.go()` in an `onBeforeAction` handler, you want `self.render('loginLayout')`

Comment: I believe you found my issue, but I don't understand very well your tip. 
Could you elaborate a bit more to help me grasp it fully?

Comment: You want to show the `email_verification_required` template when the user is not logged in. But since you're already in a route (in the `onBeforeAction` handler) you can't just go there. You can however *render* the `email_verification_required` template into the current layout. This assumes that you're using the same `layoutTemplate` for both routes.